# Reading the xml element content and attribute at the same time with c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

What I'm trying to do is exactly:
i can read xml element's value and attribute in same time.
My English is not very good. Sorry for this.

```
<all>
    <hp id="1" t="K" k="1">DÖNEN VARLIKLAR</hp>
    <hp id="10" t="K" k="10">HAZIR DEĞERLER</hp>
    <hp id="100" t="K" k="100">KASA</hp>
    <hp id="1" t="B" k="100.02">ŞUBE KASASI</hp>
    <hp id="5417" t="B" k="100.Y0001">Yeni Hesap Adı</hp>
</all>
```

this my xml file.
i want to read hp element's value and k attribute and I want to put the values I read in rows under the columns in datagridview.This my c# codes:

```
dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 2;
        dataGridView2.Columns[0].Name = "Hesap Kodu";
        dataGridView2.Columns[1].Name = "Hesap Adı";

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Luca_Offline_Yerel\hp461979110642727.xml");
        XElement rootElement = xDoc.Root;

        XmlDocument i = new XmlDocument();
        i.Load(@"C:\Luca_Offline_Yerel\hp461979110642727.xml");
        XmlNodeList xnList = i.SelectNodes("/all / hp");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //xml dosyamızı okumak için bir reader oluşturuyoruz.
        XmlReader xmlFile;
        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Luca_Offline_Yerel\hp461979110642727.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        //içeriği Dataset e aktarıyoruz.
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
        //datagridviewin kaynağı olarak dataseti gösteriyoruz.




        String Kod, Ad;
        foreach (XElement rehberimiz in rootElement.Elements())
        {
            //yapmam gereken ad'a hp nin element içeriğini ekleme! 
            Kod = rehberimiz.Attribute("k").Value;
            Ad = rehberimiz.Element("hp_Text").Value;
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(Kod, Ad);
        }
```

but i get an error on this line:

```
Ad = rehberimiz.Element("hp_Text").Value;
```

Comment: Can you add details of the error to your post?

Comment: Which error you got?

Comment: should it be Ad = rehberimiz.Element("hp").Value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        XmlNode oRootNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/all");

        foreach (XmlNode item in oRootNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            var Kod = item?.Attributes["k"]?.InnerText;
            var Ad = item?.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(Kod + " " + Ad);
        }
```

Add Kod and Ad to Row. This will resolve your problem.

Comment: No problem ☺️.You can vote this answer as your problem is resolved. Also mark this question is resolved as this is done. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FirstNode.ToString()` instead of `Element("hp_Text").Value`:

```
    String Kod, Ad;
    foreach (XElement rehberimiz in rootElement.Elements())
    {
        //yapmam gereken ad'a hp nin element içeriğini ekleme! 
        Kod = rehberimiz.Attribute("k").Value;
        Ad = rehberimiz.FirstNode.ToString();
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(Kod, Ad);
    }
```